# Log4j2 TcpSocketManager spam

Tags: java, log4j2

I have a TCP socket appender set in my Log4j2 config file but the remote receiver can periodically go offline. It works fine if the remote receiver is up and running but it start console error spam when the remote receiver is offline. In my setup it is normal situation if the remote receiver is not available.

How I can configure the Log4j to stop error message spam in case if the TCP remote receiver is not available?

The relevant part of log4j.xml is:

```
        <Socket name="ROLLING_SOCKET" host="127.0.0.1" port="18585">
            <JsonLayout />
        </Socket>
```

The error spam messages look like this:

```
2023-04-11 18:50:37,152 main ERROR TcpSocketManager (TCP:127.0.0.1:18585) caught exception and will continue: java.io.IOException: Unable to create socket for 127.0.0.1 at port 18585
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager$TcpSocketManagerFactory.createSocket(TcpSocketManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager$TcpSocketManagerFactory.createManager(TcpSocketManager.java:478)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager$TcpSocketManagerFactory.createManager(TcpSocketManager.java:459)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager.getSocketManager(TcpSocketManager.java:202)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender.createSocketManager(SocketAppender.java:443)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender$Builder.build(SocketAppender.java:221)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender$Builder.build(SocketAppender.java:195)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
    at com.zzz.test.ServerModuleUnitTest.main(ServerModuleUnitTest.java:543)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager.createSocket(TcpSocketManager.java:409)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager$TcpSocketManagerFactory.createSocket(TcpSocketManager.java:504)
    ... 27 more

2023-04-11 18:50:37,333 main ERROR Unable to write to stream TCP:127.0.0.1:18585 for appender ROLLING_SOCKET org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TCP:127.0.0.1:18585: socket not available
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager.write(TcpSocketManager.java:214)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.write(OutputStreamManager.java:190)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.writeByteArrayToManager(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:206)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender.directEncodeEvent(SocketAppender.java:459)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:190)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:181)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:542)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:483)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2017)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1983)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.warn(AbstractLogger.java:2661)
    at com.zzz.test.ServerModuleUnitTest.main(ServerModuleUnitTest.java:547)

2023-04-11 18:50:37,334 main ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender ROLLING_SOCKET org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TCP:127.0.0.1:18585: socket not available
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager.write(TcpSocketManager.java:214)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.write(OutputStreamManager.java:190)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.writeByteArrayToManager(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:206)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender.directEncodeEvent(SocketAppender.java:459)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:190)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:181)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:542)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:483)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2017)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1983)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.warn(AbstractLogger.java:2661)
    at com.zzz.test.ServerModuleUnitTest.main(ServerModuleUnitTest.java:547)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the best solutions i could came across is the solution based on the already deleted comment. It does not solve the issue because I still get a single stacktrace at the start but no more periodic spam.

The custom error handler is required:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.ErrorHandler;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;

public class TcpSocketErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public void error(String msg) {
        // Ignore errors silently
    }

    @Override
    public void error(String msg, Throwable t) {
        // Ignore errors silently
    }

    @Override
    public void error(String msg, LogEvent event, Throwable t) {
        // Ignore errors silently
    }

}
```

In the Log4j 1.x it was possible to attach a custom error handler by using a config file, but in log4j 2.x some more complex steps is needed. I've created a custom Appender that extends the SocketAppender (some of the code bellow is adapted from Log4j 2.x sources).

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.AbstractLifeCycle;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Core;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginBuilderFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.AbstractSocketManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.Advertiser;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.DatagramSocketManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.Protocol;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SocketOptions;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SslSocketManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.ssl.SslConfiguration;

@Plugin(name = "SocketNoLog", category = Core.CATEGORY_NAME, elementType = Appender.ELEMENT_TYPE, printObject = true)
public class SocketNoLogAppender extends SocketAppender {
    
    public SocketNoLogAppender(String name, Layout<? extends Serializable> layout, Filter filter,
            AbstractSocketManager manager, boolean ignoreExceptions, boolean immediateFlush, Advertiser advertiser,
            Property[] properties) {
        super(name, layout, filter, manager, ignoreExceptions, immediateFlush, advertiser, properties);
        this.setHandler(new TcpSocketErrorHandler());
    }

    @PluginBuilderFactory
    public static SocketNoLogAppender.Builder newBuilder() {
        SocketNoLogAppender.Builder bb = new SocketNoLogAppender.Builder();
        return bb;

    }
    
    /**
     * Creates an AbstractSocketManager for TCP, UDP, and SSL.
     *
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the protocol cannot be handled.
     */
    protected static AbstractSocketManager createSocketManager(final String name, Protocol protocol, final String host,
            final int port, final int connectTimeoutMillis, final SslConfiguration sslConfig,
            final int reconnectDelayMillis, final boolean immediateFail, final Layout<? extends Serializable> layout,
            final int bufferSize, final SocketOptions socketOptions) {
        if (protocol == Protocol.TCP && sslConfig != null) {
            // Upgrade TCP to SSL if an SSL config is specified.
            protocol = Protocol.SSL;
        }
        if (protocol != Protocol.SSL && sslConfig != null) {
            LOGGER.info("Appender {} ignoring SSL configuration for {} protocol", name, protocol);
        }
        switch (protocol) {
        case TCP:
            return TcpSocketManager.getSocketManager(host, port, connectTimeoutMillis, reconnectDelayMillis,
                    immediateFail, layout, bufferSize, socketOptions);
        case UDP:
            return DatagramSocketManager.getSocketManager(host, port, layout, bufferSize);
        case SSL:
            return SslSocketManager.getSocketManager(sslConfig, host, port, connectTimeoutMillis, reconnectDelayMillis,
                    immediateFail, layout, bufferSize, socketOptions);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(protocol.toString());
        }
    }
    
    public static class Builder extends SocketAppender.Builder {
        org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender.Builder parent;

        public SocketNoLogAppender build() {
            boolean immediateFlush = isImmediateFlush();
            final boolean bufferedIo = isBufferedIo();
            final Layout<? extends Serializable> layout = getLayout();
            if (layout == null) {
                AbstractLifeCycle.LOGGER.error("No layout provided for SocketAppender");
                return null;
            }

            final String name = getName();
            if (name == null) {
                AbstractLifeCycle.LOGGER.error("No name provided for SocketAppender");
                return null;
            }

            final Protocol protocol = getProtocol();
            final Protocol actualProtocol = protocol != null ? protocol : Protocol.TCP;
            if (actualProtocol == Protocol.UDP) {
                immediateFlush = true;
            }
            final AbstractSocketManager manager = SocketAppender.createSocketManager(name, actualProtocol, getHost(), getPort(),
                    getConnectTimeoutMillis(), getSslConfiguration(), getReconnectDelayMillis(), getImmediateFail(), layout, getBufferSize(), getSocketOptions());

            return new SocketNoLogAppender(name, layout, getFilter(), manager, isIgnoreExceptions(),
                    !bufferedIo || immediateFlush, getAdvertise() ? getConfiguration().getAdvertiser() : null,
                    getPropertyArray());
        }

    }

}
```

And replaced the default Appender with a custom one in my log4j.xml configuration:

```
<SocketNoLog name="ROLLING_SOCKET" host="127.0.0.1" port="18585" immediateFail="true">
    <JsonLayout />
</SocketNoLog>
```

It does not completely fix the problem but until now it is the best solution I could find.